# Enabling only TLS1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 w/ Apache 2.4

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache-2.4, openssl, apache2

I am trying to enable ONLY TLS 1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache 2.4. I have read other similar questions, but the implementations in them do not work here.

Currently TLS 1, 1.1, and 1.2 are enabled. No matter how I change my `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf` (I also changed the one under `mods-available`), and the enabled protocols do not change when testing.

I've tried all sorts of configs, including:

- `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2`
- `SSLProtocol all -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1 -SSLv3`
- `SSLProtocol TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2`

I've also restarted the apache service, even restarted the device as well. And verified the config via `apache2ctl -t`.

Why is this? How can I disable these? Is there some other config location?

**Note**: There are no other `ssl.conf` on the system, only the ones under the `apache2` directory where found via `find`.

Comment: Did you define `SSLProtocol` somewhere else?

Comment: I don't believe I did, this is a fresh instance on EC2. The only place I could find the configuration was where I listed it above. If there is a way to do a global filesearch including contents I can search for `SSLProtocol` and see what comes up?

Comment: Found it, `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` used by `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Since I was using `certbot` from Lets Encrypt, the SSL config was located at `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf`.